# Using Moment to Combine a list of hourly dates by day

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs, lodash

I have price/date data in the form of `[date, price]`

```
let priceData = [
    [1551052800000, 0.33739737955243454]
    [1551139200000, 0.33628886196814234]
    [1551225600000, 0.12674156277665535]
    [1551312000000, 0.16847247989576378]
    [1557792000000, 0.5650889670671049]
    [1557878400000, 0.6003006017008962]
    [1557964800000, 0.6438789432408669]
    [1558051200000, 0.6684895789112406]
]
```

I was wondering a clean way to take a list like this using lodash or map or something and combine it according to same dates like...

```
// the data below may not be accurate, the point here is the structure
let exampleChuckedData = [
    [
            [1551052800000, 0.33739737955243454]
            [1551139200000, 0.33628886196814234]
            [1551225600000, 0.12674156277665535]
            [1551312000000, 0.16847247989576378]
    ]
    [
            [1557792000000, 0.5650889670671049]
            [1557878400000, 0.6003006017008962]
            [1557964800000, 0.6438789432408669]
            [1558051200000, 0.6684895789112406]
    ]
]

// Or more conceptually
// Grouped by same date
let exampleConceptData = [
    [
            ['01/01/2019', 0.33739737955243454]
            ['01/01/2019', 0.33628886196814234]
            ['01/01/2019', 0.12674156277665535]
            ['01/01/2019', 0.16847247989576378]
    ]
    [
            ['01/02/2019', 0.5650889670671049]
            ['01/02/2019', 0.6003006017008962]
            ['01/02/2019', 0.6438789432408669]
            ['01/02/2019', 0.6684895789112406]
    ]
]
```

I use moment for all my date formatting needs.  Maybe there's a way to integrate moment to help with this like with their `*.isSame()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `_.groupBy()`, and in the callback convert each date to a day using `moment(date).day()`. The convert the groups' object to an array with `_.values()`:

```js
const priceData = [[1551052800000,0.33739737955243454],[1551139200000,0.33628886196814234],[1551225600000,0.12674156277665535],[1551312000000,0.16847247989576378],[1557792000000,0.5650889670671049],[1557878400000,0.6003006017008962],[1557964800000,0.6438789432408669],[1558051200000,0.6684895789112406]]

const result = _.values(_.groupBy(priceData, ([d]) => moment(d).startOf('day')
))

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.24.0/moment.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.14/lodash.js"></script>
```

Comment: I like this approach.  But it groups by same day of the week rather than grouping by same date.

Comment: See updated answer. Your data is not really showcasing the idea, but it works.

Comment: That was it!  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use moment with an object to stack up the data by dates:

**step 1:** just creating some dummy data to work with

```
const moment = require('moment');

const data = [];

for(let i = 0; i<1500; i++){
  let timestamp = moment().add(i, 'hours').format('X');
  data.push([timestamp, Math.random()*10000]);
}
```

So now there's an array with timestamps and random number data.

**Step 2**: Let's stack it by days.

An object would be more elegant in this case, since you can give the key holding the array the name of the day. This allows for a much faster comparison mechanism since javascript can find an object key faster than iterating through an array to find a matched value.

```
let stacked = {};

for(let item of data){
  // Convert timestamp to nice format of string date
  const key = moment.unix(`${item[0]}`).format('YYYY-MMM-D');
  // If already exists just add it to the object key:value by first spreading what was there and then adding the new item.
  if(stacked[key]){
    stacked[key] = [...stacked[key], item];
  } else {
    // If new then set it from the start.
    stacked[key] = [item];
  }
}
```

That's it, your data is sorted in an object by the days in this structure:

```
data: {
  day1: [
    [100, 200],
    [101, 200]
  ],
  day2: [
    [200, 200],
    [201, 200]
  ]
  //...
}
```

[Running sample](https://repl.it/repls/QuizzicalPutridTechnologies)